# Select with CASE and Union [TSQL]

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a payments table. I would like to select a few columns based on a receipt number. I would like to then display a conditional status col depending on a few values.

I have written a SQL statement that works fine just to do this:

**CODE**

```
SELECT 
    [Number], [Name], [Amount],
    CASE 
       WHEN [Downloaded by] IS NULL 
            AND [Request Accepted?] IS NULL 
          THEN 'Sent to Payments'
       WHEN [Downloaded by] IS NOT NULL 
            AND [Request Accepted?] IS NULL
          THEN 'Received by Payments'
       WHEN [Downloaded by] IS NOT NULL
            AND [Request Accepted?] IS NOT NULL 
           THEN 'Sent to Finance'
    END AS 'Real-time Status' 
FROM
    [DB] 
WHERE
    [Request Receipt Id] = 'PR0001'
```

I am building a form where users will be able to scroll through these values and I would like to display another column that is on the database. However, I do not want to show this column in the main search box. Therefore I set up the search box to contain only 4x columns (Number, Name, Amount and Real-time status).

The idea is if I have a 5th column, it wont show in the main userform unless they click on it and it will appear in another box.

My issue is setting up this SQL statement to organise the data as I want:

```
[Number], [Name], [Amount], [Real-time Status], [Description]
```

The code that I used to do this is:

```
SELECT 
    [Number], [Name], [Amount],
    CASE 
       WHEN [Downloaded by] IS NULL 
            AND [Request Accepted?] IS NULL 
          THEN 'Sent to Payments'
       WHEN [Downloaded by] IS NOT NULL 
            AND [Request Accepted?] IS NULL
          THEN 'Received by Payments'
       WHEN [Downloaded by] IS NOT NULL
            AND [Request Accepted?] IS NOT NULL 
           THEN 'Sent to Finance'
    END AS 'Real-time Status' 
FROM
    TEP_Payments_Table 
WHERE 
    [Request Receipt Id] = 'PR0001' 

UNION 

SELECT 
    [Description] 
WHERE 
    [Request Receipt Id] = 'PR0001'
```

However, when I try this, SQL Server does not like it and throws errors.

Can you guys please advise where I am going wrong and what is the most efficient way to get to what I want.

Thanks

Comment: A UNION combines multiple rowsets with the same columns.  UNION won't accomplish what you want.  You need some sort of JOIN to retrieve [Number], [Name], [Amount], [Real-time Status], [Description]

Comment: Hi - I am not familiar with Join. Can you please give me a sample syntax? Thanks

Comment: I guess I should have asked you what table [Description] is in.  Let's assume your columns are in different tables.  Then you'll have a FROM clause say FROM TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.[Request Receipt Id] = TABLE2.[Request Receipt Id] WHERE TABLE1.[Request Receipt Id] = 'PR0001'  If [Description] is not in a different table, you should just put a comma after as 'Real-time Status' and follow with [Description]

Comment: Hey - I should have elaborated, all of this data comes from 1x Table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all data comes from a single table you just need to add the description field to your query.

```
        SELECT [Number],[Name],[Amount],
        CASE WHEN [Downloaded by] is null and [Request Accepted?] is null then 'Sent to Payments'
        WHEN [Downloaded by] is not null and [Request Accepted?] is null then 'Received by Payments'
        When [Downloaded by] is not null and [Request Accepted?] is not null then 'Sent to Finance'
        END as 'Real-time Status',
        Description
     from TEP_Payments_Table where [Request Receipt Id] = 'PR0001'
```

Comment: That is elegant. I did not know you can just add columns just like that. Thank you...